Golang ReadWriteCloser as io.File
In golang having an instance of io.ReadWriteCloser how to obtain its representation (kind of proxy) as an instance of *os.File (E.g. to be provided for exec.Cmd.ExtraFiles)
The first is coming to a mind is to use os.Pipe approach. Still such a stub would be unidirectional (read or write only).
So how to completely represent io.ReadWriteCloser as an *os.File
E.g.
func something(stream io.ReadWriteCloser) {
  cmd := exec.Command("comm")

  var wrapped *os.File = wrappAsFile(stream) // How this could be achieved?

  cmd.ExtraFiles := []*File{wrapped}
}

Simplified solution I can see would be something like the following. Still (as I mentioned it before) it covers only a Reader flow.
func something(stream io.ReadWriteCloser) {
  cmd := exec.Command("comm")

  r, w, _ := os.Pipe()

  go func() {
     io.Copy(w, stream)
     w.Close()
  }()

  cmd.ExtraFiles := []*File{r}
}

Thx

You mean you want to get a os.file corresponding to io.ReadWriteCloser?

@nimdrak. No. The underling instance under io.ReadWriteCloser is not necessary os.File it self. Still it is needed to obtain a control over it in the form of a os.File (e.g.
to be able to  put it into cmd.ExtraFiles).

@nimdrak. I mean it is not a matter just of a simple type casting here.

Extended the question with another example for better understanding

You need a full duplex file handle, so you’re basically limited to creating a socket

If you can be constrained to POSIX systems, you can use a socketpair to create a full duplex pipe with syscall.Socketpair
func socketpair() (*os.File, *os.File, error) {
    fds, err := syscall.Socketpair(syscall.AF_UNIX, syscall.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    // Setnonblock may not be necessary if only using these to pass to
    // another process, but the runtime will handled it either way.
    if err := syscall.SetNonblock(int(fds[0]), true); err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    if err := syscall.SetNonblock(int(fds[1]), true); err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    f0 := os.NewFile(uintptr(fds[0]), "socket-0")
    f1 := os.NewFile(uintptr(fds[1]), "socket-1")

    return f0, f1, nil
}

Which you could then connect to an io.ReadWriteCloser with a couple io.Copy calls:
    // We'll use f0 as the local side of the pipe, and pass along f1 to the child process
    f0, f1, err := socketpair()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    go func() {
        io.Copy(f0, rw)
        f0.Close()
    }()

    go func() {
        io.Copy(rw, f0)
    }()

Windows now also supports unix domain sockets too, so while not quite as convenient as a socketpair, you can also create unix socket listener, and then dial another socket to create the connection and get the underlying files from the File() method

Oh thx!! Looks like this is it. Gonna try now.  Does it produce any artifacts on fs tree or something. I.e. should any resources cleanup being produced afterwards?

I think closing the resulting files should suffice here, a benefit of socketpair is that the files are unnamed. (as opposed to unix domain sockets, where you will end up with temp files to remove)

Didn't mention your POSIX constraint first. I'm not really familiar on that aspect. Is it the majority for linux or  more like exception? Win is not a topic. I've tested on a Mac and go playground. Both works well. What would be the behavior for non supported env? Would it just fail on a first syscall.Socketpair call? Is there any more general workaround for that? Because conceptually this solution is exactly what I expected to achieve.

The socketpair syscall doesn't exist on windows, so it won't compile.

So does the POSIX mean just any other Linux system? Including the general darwin, ubuntu, debian? The Win is the only complains on that regard?

The build constraint on that file is actually now just unix, which covers aix, android, darwin, dragonfly, freebsd, hurd, illumos, ios, linux, netbsd, openbsd, and solaris

Ah, that should. be totally enough (for my case). Thank you. And the very last question. As we have a duplex here, are these f0, f1 technically totally symmetric (i.e. no master/slave/puppet conventions to follow here)

Yes, they’re symmetrical just like if you connected unix domain sockets.
